# How to Get Unique Identity From iOS Device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uuid, udid, devicetoken

i am NewBie in iOS Development and i Know that this Question are asked many Times. i am do R&D on it but Not Get my Answer. I want to Get any Unique identity from devise. i know that there are many Option like as

```
1.UDID
2.UUID
```

But From iOS 7 Apple not accept app that Fetch `UDID` From Devise so that Option is Block For me. and Now Second Option is `UUID` But From my R&D Result `UUID` will be Changed Every time when User Completely Uninstall application and Reinstall it. So, I Get Different `UUID` for Same Device. and Another Option is like as

```
Device Token
```

Here I want to Know that for Push Notification Service `Device Token` are remaining same for Every time When User Uninstall app and Reinstall it. if Device token are Different for Every Uninstall and Reinstallation Process then please Give me Any Solution for Unique Identification that are Remaining same for every time.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save UUID in the keychain, so even uninstall and reinstall app, you still can get it back.

Comment: how to Save UUID in KeyChain Please Give me Any Solution or any Resource link about that and if i save UUID in KeyChain then For All Device UUID is remainning  Same or Not?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to uniquely identify devices, you may want to use `[UIDevice identifierForVendor]` which will stay the same as long as the apps come from the same vendor and running on the same device.

See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor).